# windows form load in c#

Tags: c#

I am writing a program which reads input file and then display the names list to the user.
I am coding as follows:

```
Read the txt file
Store the data in a list
then call a method userint.add_names(names); //where names is a list containing first name and last name.
Created a new method in userint.cs as follows:
internal void add_localvars(List<names> name)
        {
            userinter userinterface = new userinter();
            InitializeComponent();
            listbox1.DataSource = name;
            listbox1.DisplayMember = "first_name"; 
            userInterface.Activate();
            userinterface.Show();
        }
```

I am not sure why my form is not loaded. I get error in last statement activate form and also I am not sure how to load the form. I have tried hundred different things on internet. Can anyone please help.

Thanks

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Did you initialize `userInterface` ?

Comment: I did that it's not giving me error now. But its not loading the form.

Comment: Right, but do you have an instance of that class somewhere that calls Show() ?

Comment: I tried that also but its not working. It opens the window and the it stops working. I have updated my code.

Comment: try using `ShowDialog` instead of `Show`

Comment: Please put the entire form code behind to us. You will have the solution for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much actually it worked...when i changed from show() to showDialog().

Comment: Glad if it worked, but also keep in mind that ShowDialog() is modal and Show() is modeless. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also drop the calls to InitialiseComponent and Activate. These will be handled by the designer code and the natural order of events. Should make your code a little lighter.